# Apache 2, Zend redirecting to Angular 2 App

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework, angular-cli

I, have problem with merging old zend website with new Angular 2/4 app. I would like to insert my angular app as another url in zend.

So i have domain http://example.net, which redirect me to my zend website,
now i want to have http://example.net/Angular, which redirect me to my Angular app.

In zend public folder i created another one, and copied all compiled files from angular2. Everything works great when i go to http://example.net/Angular, i can move through website using links, but when i refresh or send more nested link like http://example.net/Angular/profile/12 i am being redirected to zend 404 page.

**Angular app .htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Zend .htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI


php_value upload_max_filesize 24M
php_value post_max_size 24M
php_value memory_limit 512M

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
#https:// -> https://www.
php_value safe_mode "0"

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} msnbot [NC]
  RewriteRule . - [F]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.net [NC]
  #^ -> https://www.
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.net%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    #http -> https
  # newsletter stats collector
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/ns/[0-9]+/[^/]+$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ _newsletter_stats.php [L]

RewriteRule ^action/order.php order.php [L]

  # newsletter tracker
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/nt/[0-9]+$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ _newsletter_tracker.php [L]

  ErrorDocument 404 /404.html


  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.pdf$
  RewriteRule .* - [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f


  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript application/x-javascript
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
    mod_gzip_on       Yes
    mod_gzip_dechunk  Yes
    mod_gzip_item_include file      \.(html?|txt|js|php|pl|jpg|png|gif|css)$
    mod_gzip_item_include handler   ^cgi-script$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime      ^text/.*
    mod_gzip_item_include mime      ^application/x-javascript.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime      ^image/.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
# Netscape 4.x has some problems�
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

# Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

# MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

# NOTE: Due to a bug in mod_setenvif up to Apache 2.0.48
# the above regex won�t work. You can use the following
# workaround to get the desired effect:
#BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

# Don�t compress already-compressed files
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .(?:exe|t?gz|zip|bz2|sit|rar)$ no-gzip dont-vary
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .(?:avi|mov|mp3|mp4|rm|flv|swf|mp?g)$ no-gzip dont-vary
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .pdf$ no-gzip dont-vary
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch ".(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|swf|css)$">
  <IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault A604800
    Header append Cache-Control "public"
  </IfModule>
  Header unset ETag
  FileETag None
</FilesMatch>
```

Routing system in this app is probably unknown to people that coded this site, so i would like to stick to htaccess and Angular solutions.

Also i can't run node server or any other then this Apache 2 i already have... Hosting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely recommend to use an [Alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) for the angular app (even in terms of deployment, that means you keep your projects and artefacts separated).

The first `.htaccess` you provided is probably not even requested, as you query the document_root `/` (being your ZF app), which verifies whether the file exists on the disk, see that  `/Angular/profile/12` does not and serves the `index.php`.

The other solution would therefore be adding another condition in the ZF `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /

    #...

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(?!Angular/)(.+)$ /index.html/$1 [NC,QSA,L]

    #...
</IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
```

Something like that (not tested).

---

Edit: what about that

```
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/Angular/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}/Angular/index.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
```

Again that might need some tweaking, and other solutions such as Aliases or a domain per website (app.domain.com and api.domain.com) would be way better.

Comment: You are right, the first .htaccess is not required, however code you provided cause 500 internal server error on every nested URL.

Comment: Can you access Apache error logs? I'll edit my post with a possibly better redirect